# Drag and Drop API with React not dropping or returning id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm following [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reactjs-implement-drag-and-drop-feature-without-using-external-libraries-ad8994429f1a/) tutorial and I'm having trouble with the onDragStart and onDragOver not returning and information. More context, I'm making a sticky note type app.

```
  onDragStart = (e, id) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("id", id);
  };

  onDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  onDrop = (e, sect) => {
    let id = e.dataTransfer.setData("id", e.target.id);

    let notes = this.state.notes.filter((note) => {
      console.log(id);
      if (note.key == id) {
        note.section = sect;
      }
      return note;
    });

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      notes,
    });
  };
```

This is the code I used that is not working properly. I can drag the notes but they don't drop. I believe this is because variable `id` is undefined for some reason. For example, if I removed the `(note.key == id)` the notes would drop correctly into place (but every note would and not the specific one I want).

As for the Sticky notes and droppable area, here is the code.

```
this.state.notes.forEach((n) => {
      sections[n.section].push(
        <Sticky
          key={n.key}
          onDragStart={(e) => this.onDragStart(e, n.key)}
          id={n.key}
          text={n.text}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container-drag">
          <h2 className="header">General</h2>
          <div
            id="general"
            className="droppable"
            onDragOver={(e) => this.onDragOver(e)}
            onDrop={(e) => {
              this.onDrop(e, "general");
            }}
          >
            {sections.general}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="container-drag">
          <h2 className="header">Todo</h2>
          <div
            id="todo"
            className="droppable"
            onDragOver={(e) => this.onDragOver(e)}
            onDrop={(e) => {
              this.onDrop(e, "todo");
            }}
          >
            {sections.todo}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And the sticky component is simply

```
      <div id={this.props.id} className="draggable" draggable>
        <p>{this.props.text}</p>
      </div>
```

I don't think the problem is with the state so I'll leave that out, it is just an array of objects. In addition, I've tried using `text` instead of `id` but I was a bit confused so maybe I did something incorrectly. Basically, I've tried console.logging everything individually with no success. I'm not sure the problem but I found that copy-pasting the tutorials code made it work perfectly (but I still wanted my own take of it, with separate components).

Hopefully I can find a solution and I appreciate any help or tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
 onDragStart = (e, id) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData("id", id); //in brackets should be ("text/plain", id) and in the .getData below it should be (text", id)
  };

  onDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  onDrop = (e, sect) => {
    let id = e.dataTransfer.setData("id", e.target.id); //this shoud be .getData not .setData
```

And finally,

```
<Sticky
          key={n.key}
          onDragStart={(e) => this.onDragStart(e, n.key)}
          id={n.key}
          text={n.text}
        />
```

The onDragStart was being passed as a property not an actual function, I solved this by changing it to a